# Hibernate v5->v6 upgrade - poor SELECT performance

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jpa, orm

I've upgraded an application using Hibernate v5 to v6, but after doing this a query has got very slow - >10x slower.

Take the following simple application that persists 500,000 `MyEntity`s to a new in-memory database, retrieves them and prints performance metrics. It can be run with either Hibernate v5 or v6, as per the commented out section in `pom.xml`:

`MyApplication.java`:

```
package com.me;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import org.h2.Driver;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.Action;

public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Instant start = Instant.now();

    final Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:mem:");
    jpaProperties.put("jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver", Driver.class.getName());
    jpaProperties.put("jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", Action.CREATE);

    try (Session session = new Configuration().addAnnotatedClass(MyEntity.class).addProperties(jpaProperties)
        .buildSessionFactory().openSession()) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        IntStream.range(0, 500000).mapToObj(i -> new MyEntity()).forEach(session::persist);
        printTiming(start, "Setup / Publish");

        start = Instant.now();
        session.createQuery("FROM MyEntity", MyEntity.class).getResultList();
        printTiming(start, "Get");
    }
    }

    private static void printTiming(final Instant startTime, final String label) {
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("{0} took {1}", label, Duration.between(startTime, Instant.now())));
    }
}
```

`MyEntity.java`:

```
package com.me;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
}
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>hibernate-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core-jakarta</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`hibernate-core` `6.1.5`:

```
Setup / Publish took PT2.6288547S
Get took PT35.0881315S
```

`hibernate-core-jakarta` `5.6.14.Final`:

```
Setup / Publish took PT3.486003S
Get took PT2.3955987S
```

I've profiled it I can see Hibernate 6 is spending ~90% of the time in `org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.withDuplicationCheck()` - some kind of results post-processing.

Comment: Is this of use? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-distinct - I know it says it applies to "join fetch" but might there be something going on under the covers?

Comment: @JimGarrison I found that, but I have no joins to adjust the fetch type on. But you’d assume that if what I’m seeing is right, others would have the same problem. But they don’t, so I must have something wrong…

Comment: Whatever is wrong is not in the code you've shown us... maybe in a config somewhere?  Something obviously thinks it needs to do duplicate elimination.

Comment: @Jakg I do believe your issue will be addressed in HBN 6.1.6: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15719

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov that sounds like it might be exactly my problem - do you know if there's any workaround? E.G. manually setting a queryhint, or some pre-release artefact I can test with?

Comment: See https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-v5-v6-upgrade-poor-query-performance/6981 for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments that is HBN issue introduced in [HHH-15133](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15133) and somehow addressed in upcoming releases:

- [HHH-15719](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15719)
- [HHH-15479](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15479)

Possible workarounds at the current moment are:

1. ask query to return stream instead of list:

```java
try (Stream<MyEntity> stream = session.createQuery("FROM MyEntity", MyEntity.class).getResultStream()) {
   return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

2. select tuples instead of entities (stream option seems to be more convenient):

```java
List<Object[]> tuples = session.createQuery("select e.id, e FROM MyEntity e", Object[].class).getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks - using a `Stream` and then `toList` seems to work around it, suggesting it's the bug you've mentioned.

Comment: Thanks again - just benchmarked it again in Hibernate v6.1.5 @ 37 seconds, v6.1.6 @ 3 seconds.